# Unable to merge dataframes due to special symbols

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have 2 dataframes like this:

In the below dataframe, there are 297 rows and 5 columns. Here many values for EAN and Class are empty.

```
Item name     category     EAN    Class   Manufacturer
Soya Chunks   Vegetable     12            XY Priate ltd
Amul Butter   Dairy                       AB Private ltd
```

In this second dataframe, only 156 rows and 2 columns is there.

```
Item name     category     
Rich Refined    Oil       
Soya-chunks    Vegetables
```

I want to merge these 2 dataframes so that if there is some item in dataframe1 which is not presnt in
dataframe2, then it will be included in merged dataframe and also if there is some item in dataframe2 which is not presnt in
dataframe1, then it will also be included in merged dataframe. If some items from datafraeme2 are included in merged dataframe, then its EAN and Class can be left blanked.

So, i simply tried pd.merge(df1, df2, on='item name') but the result was complelety incorrect.

It is unable to recognise the special symbols such as 'soya chunks' and 'soya-chunks' as same. Also, hence
there are some missing column values in dataframe1 is also creating problems in merging the dataframes.

Comment: You've answered your own question.  If you have have not performed DQ / normalisation on your data you cannot and should not expect operations on data to magically resolve fundamental DQ issues